# ! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, r-markdown

When using R Markdown to create a pdf a get this error:

```
output file: NCERA-210_Results.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined.

Error: Failed to compile NCERA-210_Results.tex. See NCERA-210_Results.log for more info.
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Execution halted
```

My code is:

````
---
title: "NCERA-210 Results"
author: "NAME"
date: "8/29/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, results="asis", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

# load packages
library("MOTE")
library("tidyverse")
library("broom")
library("ggpubr")
library("markovchain")
library("gmodels")
library("scales")
library("formattable")
library("rmarkdown")
library("knitr")
library("igraph")
library("papaja")
library("citr")
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results="hide", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,       
fig.show="hide"} 
source("Thesis_Code.R")  
```

## Summary of Ratings
```{r 'Table Rating Count', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
apa_table(rating.dist,
caption = "Count of Ratings in Dataset")
```

## Plot of Rating Distribution
```{r 'Plot of Rating Distribution', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

ggplot(rating.dist,
   aes(Rating, Count)) + 
geom_col() +
ggtitle("Distribution of Ratings")
```

## Summary of Short Ratings
```{r 'Table Short Rating Count', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
apa_table(s_rating.dist,
caption = "Count of Short Ratings in Dataset")
```

## Plot of Short Rating Distribution
```{r 'Plot of Short Rating Distribution', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

ggplot(s_rating.dist,
   aes(Short_Rating, Count)) + 
geom_col() +
ggtitle("Distribution of Short Ratings")
```

## Summary of Co-op Location Distribution
```{r 'Co-op Distribution', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
apa_table(state.dist,
caption = "Location Distribution in Dataset")
```

## Plot of Co-op Distribution
```{r 'Plot of Co-op Distribution', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

ggplot(state.dist,
   aes(State, Count)) + 
geom_col() +
ggtitle("Distribution of Cooperatives Across the U.S.")
```

## Co-op Activity
```{r 'Co-op Activity Summary',echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

apa_table(coop_activity,
      caption = "Count of Co-ops by Activity")
```

## Co-op Sales Quartiles by Decade & Short Rating
```{r 'Sales Quartiles', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

apa_table(sales.qt,
caption = "Co-op Sales Quartiles by Decade & Short Rating")
```

## Co-op Liabilities by Decade & Short Rating
```{r 'Liabilities Quartiles', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

apa_table(liab.qt,
caption = "Co-op Liabilities Quartiles by Decade & Short Rating")
```

## Co-op Cash Patronage Paid by Decade & Short Rating
```{r 'Cash Patronage Paid Quartiles', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}

apa_table(pat.paid,
      caption = "Co-op Cash Patronage Paid Quartiles by Decade & Short Rating")
```
````

I am using the papaja package to produce an APA style manuscript. I'm able to create word documents with the Rmd script but I get that error when the output is pdf_document. However, I am able to create a manuscript using the papaja template "APA article (6th edition) but this route requires a lot of script editing to remove the unnecessary code.

I suppose the issue has to do with threepartabble but I can't seem to find any guidance on this using R. I am using a Mac and have MacTex installed.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your document?

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is better to edit the answer to include the extra details :) comments mangle the formatting

Comment: @MikeyHarper I've included my code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The fix was installing "kableExtra" For some reason the pdf does not render without it.

Comment: I had the same issue. The fix work, but I needed to have `kableExtra` loaded in my environment as well. Just wanted to share that aspect of it. Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: This solution no longer appears to work. Please see the following thread for the new solution, which requires an update to RMarkdown: remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')

Answer (score 2):

This proposed solution no longer appears to work.

Please see the following thread: [LaTeX Error: Environment ThreePartTable undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245638/latex-error-environment-threeparttable-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1)  for the new solution, which requires an update to RMarkdown by running:

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

That will correct the conflict between the threeparttablex latex package and rmarkdown. You may also have to run the following to manually install the package, as [mentioned on the tinytex page](https://yihui.org/tinytex/), if bookdown does not automatically do so:

```
library(tinytex)
tlmgr_install('threeparttablex')    # install the threeparttablex package
tlmgr_update()               # update everything
```

Finally, I found it was necessary to terminate your R session and restart, so that book the rmarkdown package and the updated latex package were available. After that, you can use apa_table with results='as-is', for example:

````
```{r apatable, results='asis'}

  apa_table(head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!')  

```
````

And, bookdown will also take care of the labeling as it would do with its own knitr::kable based tables.