# LaTeX Error: Environment ThreePartTable undefined

Tags: r, r-markdown, longtable, papaja

I am trying to create a table using `apa_table()`, Papaja, and RMarkdown in RStudio. Whenever I include `longtable` in the `apa_table` function, I get the error:

`! LaTeX Error: Environment ThreePartTable undefined.`

Strangely, the error log that's produced includes:

```
(/home/tim/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty
Package: threeparttable 2003/06/13  v 3.0
```

and

`Package caption Info: threeparttable package is loaded.`

Note the different capitalization between the error and the loaded package, which makes me wonder if that's the issue.

Note that this is the same error as reported in an earlier question: [! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090721/latex-error-environment-threeparttable-undefined). However, the solution provided there does not work for me.

I'm not sure if this will be reproducible outside of my particular setup, but here is some code that produces the problem for me.

Note that I do not have the same issue if I simply use `kable()` (also included below).

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"
  - name          : "Ernst-August Doelle"
    affiliation   : "1,2"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"
  - id            : "2"
    institution   : "Konstanz Business School"

authornote: |


abstract: |


keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : yes
mask              : no
draft             : no
tables            : yes

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("papaja")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
```

```{r, results="asis"}
kable(mtcars, longtable=TRUE)
```

```{r, results="asis"}
apa_table(mtcars, longtable=TRUE)
```

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}

<div id = "refs"></div>
\endgroup
````

Here is the output from `sessionInfo()` in case it helps:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        digest_0.6.23     crayon_1.3.4      withr_2.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1  evaluate_0.14     rlang_0.4.2      
 [8] cli_1.1.0         rstudioapi_0.10   rmarkdown_1.18    tools_3.6.1       xfun_0.11         yaml_2.2.0        compiler_3.6.1   
[15] sessioninfo_1.1.1 papaja_0.1.0.9842 htmltools_0.4.0   knitr_1.26
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `threeparttablex` style for the `ThreePartTable` environment. In principle `papaja` tries to load this style, but there seems to be an incompatibility with recent `rmarkdown`. Since this seems to be a regression in `rmarkdown`, I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1729) for it. As a workaround you can downgrade to an older version of `rmarkdown`. Meanwhile, you can also install a fixed version from GitHub: `remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`.

Comment: Downgrading `rmarkdown` to 1.17 fixed the issue for me. If anyone else has the problem and isn't sure how to install an earlier version of an R package, how to do so can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840882/11082069 (changing the various arguments to suit the current situation).

Comment: The Github issue has been resolved, so you may try `remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')` or wait for the next CRAN release of **rmarkdown**. Thank you!

Comment: @TimBainbridge See the comment by Yihui Xie. The issue has been fixed in the development version of rmarkdown.