# Bookdown/rmarkdown: "Could not find data file templates/--number-sections.latex Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97"

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

Following: `render_book("index.Rmd")`
I was getting this other error associated with three part table: 
[LaTeX Error: Environment ThreePartTable undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245638/latex-error-environment-threeparttable-undefined) 
I applied the solution suggested there(`remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`). Now I have this error:
"Could not find data file templates/--number-sections.latex
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97"

My index.Rmd looks like this:

```
title: "Figures and Tables"
author: "name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"

output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: oneside
linestretch: 2
documentclass: book
bibliography: "bibs.bib"
biblio-style: "apalike"
geometry: "left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in"
---
```

preamble.tex has:

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagestyle{plain}
\raggedbottom
```

While `render_book("index.Rmd")` does not generate a pdf and gives me this pandoc error, it successfully generates a merged markdown file "FiguresTables.Rmd." When I try to knit the merged file it works, it does generate the pdf. I just cannot figure-out why I am unable to generate the pdf from `render_book("index.Rmd")`.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind! Writing the question made me think of an answer. I just re-installed r-markdown from the cran repository instead of github and tried again. And it works fine now.